# How can I access the main object from inside a namespace?

Tags: ruby

I'm refactoring some debug tools that get loaded into a Rails console. The debug tools used to use global variables that get modified in code, but for obvious reasons, I want to restrict that to a namespace, so I'm throwing everything into a class and using class instance variables instead.

At certain points, these tools need to call `#reload!` in the console, which is defined on the `main` object. Once I move the tools into a new class, the `main` defined methods are no longer accessible. Is there a good way way to access `main` from inside a namespace so that I can call `#reload!` on it?

Right now, I have a working hack with `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver.reload!` but I'm sure there's got to be a better way. A better solution could be instructive about Ruby namespaceing too.

e.g.

```
class MyAwesomeTools
  def reload!
    # or whatever executes #reload! with main as the receiver
    MAIN_NAMESACE.reload!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a neater option than `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver` to access `main`; it's really not something one should often need to get to.

To do the Rails-specific thing you described, however, I recommend skipping the console helper and calling the 'real' reload method directly:

```
Rails.application.reloader.reload!
```

That's [all the helper method does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/241bbf268cca61c42b61076deead699010068968/railties/lib/rails/console/app.rb#L31-L36) (as of Rails 5.0+; it was [spelt slightly differently](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3804d017333da16d76d9fc6633faf5635c7b03d7/railties/lib/rails/console/app.rb#L24-L30) before that).